# Do i need to validate variables again in router.get method after validating in router.use method?

Tags: node.js, validation, express

I am using Nodejs and Express framework and mysql as database

i am validating data in the use method only

what i don't understand is should i validate data again in the get method ?

i have this code

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

function isNullOrWhitespace(input) {
if (typeof input === 'undefined' || input == null) return true;
return input.replace(/\s/g, '').length < 1;
}

function hasWhiteSpace(s) {
return /\s/g.test(s);
}



router.use(function(req, res, next) {
var auth_key = req.headers['auth_key'];
var api_key = req.query['api_key'];
var source_id = req.query['source_id'];
if( (auth_key) && (api_key) && (source_id) && (auth_key!==undefined) && (api_key!==undefined) &&(source_id!==undefined) && !isNullOrWhitespace(auth_key) && !isNullOrWhitespace(api_key) && !isNullOrWhitespace(source_id) && !hasWhiteSpace(auth_key) && !hasWhiteSpace(api_key) && !(hasWhiteSpace(source_id)))
{
next();
}
else
{
    if( (!auth_key) || (auth_key===undefined) || isNullOrWhitespace(auth_key) || hasWhiteSpace(auth_key))
    {
        var auth_key_error = {
        status : "fail",
        message : "Invalid Auth Key"
    };


        return res.status(403).send(auth_key_error);
}
    else if((!api_key) || (api_key===undefined) || isNullOrWhitespace(api_key) || hasWhiteSpace(api_key))
    {
        var api_key_error = {
            status : "fail",
            message : "Invalid API Key"
        };


        return res.status(403).send(api_key_error);

    }
    else if((!source_id) || (source_id===undefined) || isNullOrWhitespace(source_id) || hasWhiteSpace(source_id))
    {
        var sourceid_error = {
            status : "fail",
            message : "Invalid Source ID"
        };


        return res.status(403).send(sourceid_error);

    }
    else{
        var fieldsempty_error = {
            status : "fail",
            message : "Some field was incorrect or left empty"
        };


        return res.status(403).send(fieldsempty_error);
    }
}

});

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {


var auth_key = req.headers['auth_key'];
var api_key = req.query['api_key'];
var source_id = req.query['source_id'];
//do something here





});

module.exports = router;
```

now i want to use the header[] and query string [] variables again in the get method

how should i access those variables in get method properly?

also what is sanitization ?

do i need to perform sanitization for the variables in this code ?

also one more thing .. i read that the next method is used to execute the next order middleware function

what should we do if we only have one use function for middleware ?

Answer (score 0):

Logically your data validation might differ from one route end point to another, so it's better to not use route.use() but use methods according to verbs you are using (get, post, delete ...).

Use [express-validator](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator) to validate your data, it gives the possibility to make async/synchron validation in a human readable uniform code.

To access get data, they are usally in the req.query, if the url sent is:
host.com?data1=x ==> req.query.data1

if they are in the body, which is usally the case for post/put/patch requests, use req.body.data1.

to access your data, you have to encode them. if you sent your data in json form, then you should decode them before accessing them, using some middleware for this purpose, to be able to access them like this:
req.body.name ....